# React JS pass state altering function to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a react js project for one of my classes and cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong. I cannot post any code for this, and I understand that this may make it fairly hard to answer this question, but here is my problem.

I have a parent function, which has a state that decides between 3 different possible components to render as the page depending on the state variable '`currentPage`'. In this parent component, I have made functions that will alter the `currentPage` state variable. I am trying to pass these state altering functions through props and then call them inside of the children components to change the state of the parent and re-render the page. For example, I have a function called signup which changes the currentPage to '`signup`', so I have `<Login goToSignup = {this.signup} />`. Then, inside of my Login component, I try to set the on click of a button to: `onClick = {this.props.goToSignup}`. But this doesn't seem to work. I am very new to react and am maybe misunderstanding how I am supposed to do this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, there are 3 components `Detail, Post, XYZ` and a parent component `App`. On the basis of `state` value in parent, `rendering` the different component. In all the 3 component passing a `function` that is used to change the `currentPage` state value in parent component.

For `Stateless Functional Component`, check the [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components).

Check this example:

```js
var Post = (props) => {
    return <div onClick={()=>props.changeComponent('detail')}> POST </div>
}
var Detail = (props) => {
    return <div onClick={()=>props.changeComponent('xyz')}> DETAIL </div>
}
var XYZ = (props) => {
    return <div onClick={()=>props.changeComponent('post')}> XYZ </div>
}    

class App extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {currentPage: 'post'}
      this.changeComponent = this.changeComponent.bind(this)
   }
   
   changeComponent(currentPage){
      this.setState({currentPage});
   }
   
   renderTab(){
      switch(this.state.currentPage){
         case 'post': return <Post changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
         case 'detail': return <Detail changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
         case 'xyz': return <XYZ changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
      }
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            {this.renderTab()}
            <div style={{marginTop: 100}}>*Click on Page name to render different page</div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
```

**Update** (OP asked for same example in `es5`)

Same example written in `ES5` (don't know much about `es5`, correct me if i did some mistake):

```js
function Post(props) {
    return <div onClick={()=>props.changeComponent('detail')}> POST </div>
}
function Detail(props){
    return <div onClick={()=>props.changeComponent('xyz')}> DETAIL </div>
}
function XYZ(props){
    return <div onClick={()=>props.changeComponent('post')}> XYZ </div>
}    

var App = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function(){
      return (
          {currentPage: 'post'}
      )
   },
   
   changeComponent: function(currentPage){
      this.setState({currentPage});
   },
   
   renderTab: function(){
      switch(this.state.currentPage){
         case 'post': return <Post changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
         case 'detail': return <Detail changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
         case 'xyz': return <XYZ changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
      }
   },
   
   render: function(){
      return(
         <div>
            {this.renderTab()}
            <div style={{marginTop: 100}}>*Click on Page name to render different page</div>
         </div>
      )
   }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
```

Comment: What exactly does the (props) => do and the ()=>props.changeCompnent, like why can't you do this.props?

Comment: its a `stateless functional component`, `this` keyword will not be available in this. It's a another way of writting the `react` components, where state is not required. check the article: https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d

Comment: `(props) => {}` is called arrow function, you can avoid this and directly use `function abc(props){}`. These are `es6` awesome stuffs :)

Comment: Will this syntax still work if I'm not using the extends version, I'm using something like var Page = React.createClass ({....})

Comment: code will work but few things you need to change since they are not present in `es5` like constructor. one more thing in `es5` auto binding is there so no need to bind the method manually, do the changes it will surely work :) let me know if you need any help to convert it into `es5` :)

Comment: How exactly do I convert it? I'm currently using the set up given on codecademy, so I'm using babel and web pack right now.

Comment: So I am trying to do the version above and it keeps saying props is not defined. I have my other pages in other files, does that make a difference?

Comment: are you using stateless functional component or stateful? can you show the code of that file ?